# How can I install all dependencies when installing from source, without making my own repository?

Tags: r, installation, package

I have developed an R package that I would like to share with other people from my group. For now, it has to be kept private, so I can't submit it to CRAN. When installing with `install.packages('package.tar.gz', repos = NULL, type="source")` it does not download and install the packages from CRAN because repos is `NULL`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/5805149/651779 gives a method by making my own repository. However, I don't have access to a server to share my own made repository with other people.

Is there a way to automatically download and install all the dependencies from CRAN when installing from source, without making your own directory?

Comment: Your linked question contains a [non-accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15915876/602276) with instructions for using `devtools::install()` to do this.

Comment: @Pascal I added a link to the answer to that question in my post. I want something differently. Please read the rest of my question.

Comment: @Andrie I will use that if there is no other option, but would prefer a method where the other users don't have to install the devtools package first

Comment: In that case I suggest you write a script that pre-installs all the dependencies from CRAN and then installs your package locally from source. This is just one additional line of code you have to distribute.