# Install a local R package with dependencies from CRAN mirror

Tags: r, dependencies, repository, package, cran

I have built an R package, i.e. I have the mypackage.tar.gz file. This package depends on several other packages, all downloadable and installable from any CRAN mirror.

Now I want to install this package on a system where the dependencies are not yet installed, and I would like that the dependencies will be downloaded and installed automatically when I install my package.

I tried:

```
install.packages("mypackage.tar.gz",type="source",dependencies=TRUE,repos="http://a.cran.mirror")
```

but it searches for `mypackage.tar.gz` on the mirror (and obviously it does not find), while if I set `repos=NULL` it correctly tries to install the local package file (as documented), but obviously it does not find the dependencies packages.

**So my question is: is there a way to perform a 'mixed' installation (local package with online dependencies) or the only way to do is to manually install all the dependencies?**

Comment: Related (and possibly duplicate): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805049/package-dependencies-when-installing-from-source-in-r?rq=1

Comment: Flabbergasted that R does not provide a mechanism to do this by default. Isn't this package management 101?

Comment: @BradSolomon R does provide the mechanism for it. See my answer.

Answer (score 9):

You could use `install` from the devtools package. Just run `install("<directory of your package>", dependencies = TRUE)`. Its help states:

> Uses R CMD INSTALL to install the package. Will also try to install dependencies of the package from CRAN, if they're not already installed.

Answer (score 6):

Here, I'm using `untar()` with `devtools::install()` and passing in a directory to which the source tarball has been extracted.

```
d <- tempdir()
untar("mypackage.tar.gz", compressed="gzip", exdir=d)
devtools::install(file.path(d, "mypackage"), dependencies=TRUE,
                  repos="https://cloud.r-project.org/")
```

If you want to install from multiple repos, you can provide a list of them. For example, to use both [Bioconductor](http://bioconductor.org) and CRAN, you could run:

```
 devtools::install(file.path(d, "mypackage"), dependencies=TRUE,
                   repos=BiocManager::repositories())
```

NOTE: *I can't figure out how to directly pass the tarball to `install()`, but this solution works in the meantime and leaves no clutter because we extract to a temp directory. It seems `install_local()` should be able to take a tarball, but I am getting an error when attempting to do so.*

Comment: `install_local()` worked exactly as needed for me.

Answer (score 4):

If you already have installed your local package, you should be able to use a couple functions in **tools** to install the dependencies from CRAN:

```
library('tools')
installFoundDepends(pkgDepends('mypackage', local = FALSE)$Found)
```

Note: You can pass args (like `repos`) through `installFoundDepends` to `install.packages`.

You can also use the `Depends` element from the `pkgDepends` output to pass directly to `install.packages`:

```
install.packages(pkgDepends('mypackage')$Depends)
```

UPDATE: Apparently it is not possible to install a local package with `dependencies=FALSE`. This seems odd, since you can do that for a remote package from a repository. The reason ([looking at the source code](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/9ee3012c11b299efd1b4d93ea3d20a8d7475a17e/src/library/utils/R/packages2.R)) is that `if(is.null(repos) & missing(contriburl))`, installation is handled via system calls to `R CMD INSTALL`, which has no dependency-related arguments.

Comment: I can not install my local package if I don't have yet installed all its dependencies.

Comment: unfortunately it does not work, even with dependencies set to FALSE, actually the man page clearly specify that with repos set to NULL (needed to install a local package), the dependencies parameter is ignored.

Comment: @WoDoSc Okay, many further tests reveals this is really annoying and surprising. I actually think that being able to install local packages without dependencies is a pretty reasonable feature request for R that would be worth submitting.

Answer (score 3):

If you are not opposed to using another package who manages this for you, this can nowadays be easily achieved with the {remotes} package.

```
install.packages("remotes")
remotes::install_local("mypackage.tar.gz")
```

You can specify some further options which dependencies you want (e.g. also those in 'Suggests') etc.:

```
?remotes::install_local
```

{remotes} itself does not have dependencies afaik, so it does not add too much clutter to your environment.

Answer (score 2):

So old question and so many answers but unfortunately none of them presents the canonical way to address the problem.
R was designed to handle situations like this, no extra packages are needed. One has to create local repository, and then use it, together with CRAN url, as a repository source when installing.
Below is code that present complete process.

```r
## double check our dependency is not yet installed
## remove.packages("data.table")
"data.table" %in% rownames(installed.packages())
#[1] FALSE

## create our pkg
hello = function() "world"
package.skeleton(name="pkg", list="hello")
#...
cat("Imports: data.table\n", file="pkg/DESCRIPTION", append=TRUE)
unlink(c("pkg/Read-and-delete-me", "pkg/man"), recursive=TRUE)
rm(hello)

## publish our pkg in current working directory
system("R CMD build pkg")
#...
dir.create("src/contrib", recursive=TRUE)
file.rename("pkg_1.0.tar.gz", "src/contrib/pkg_1.0.tar.gz")
#[1] TRUE
tools::write_PACKAGES("src/contrib")

## install pkg and its dependencies automatically
install.packages("pkg", repos=c(
  paste0("file://", getwd()),
  "https://cloud.r-project.org"
))
#Installing package into '/home/jan/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2'
#(as 'lib' is unspecified)
#also installing the dependency 'data.table'
#...

## test
library(pkg)
hello()
#[1] "world

"data.table" %in% rownames(installed.packages())
#[1] TRUE
```

On windows one may need to specify `type="source"` and amend paths.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for.