# Error while installing R package in AWS

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ec2-ami

I am using a ubuntu AMI in my AWS and have launched a R studio server.

I am finding trouble in installing the R packages.

Whenever I try to install the packages I get an error

```
> Installing package into
> ‘/home/rstudio2/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0’ (as ‘lib’ is
> unspecified) Warning in install.packages :   dependency ‘xml2’ is not
> available also installing the dependencies ‘jsonlite’, ‘mime’, ‘curl’,
> ‘openssl’, ‘R6’, ‘httr’, ‘base64enc’, ‘digest’, ‘aws.signature’
> 
> 
> The downloaded source packages are in
>   ‘/tmp/Rtmp1BrKS6/downloaded_packages’
```

Could anyone help me to backtrace the reason for error. Would be thankful, I have spent almost a day . could not figure out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dependency ‘xml2’ is not available
```

From this error, we can understand that package `XML2` is missing. You need to install the system library `libxml2-dev` to install the `XML2` package. So use the following command to install the package:

```
sudo apt install libxml2-dev
```

After this proceed with R package installation.

Comment: @venkatest : I would like to know, suppose if i would need VIm package, is it  something like the above that i need to first install dependencies and then try installing the package ?

Comment: I tried to download an another package VIM ; I get an error ERROR: **compilation failed for package ‘VIM’
 removing ‘/home/rstudio2/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/VIM
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘VIM had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
 ‘/tmp/RtmpDeIfw7/downloaded_packages’** Could you tell me where I am making mistake

Comment: @Rohi: can you Install R package with dependencies from CRAN mirror as mentioned in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25017195/install-a-local-r-package-with-dependencies-from-cran-mirror

Comment: It dint work for me .. I tried all the possible ways i coul