# R:How to automatically load dependent packages when i install package by .gz file?

Tags: r, package

I'm coding a R package, and in DESCRIPTION file:

```
Imports: stringr,splitstackshape
```

in NAMESPACE file:

```
import(splitstackshape)
import(stringr)
```

but when i load this package locally:

```
install.packages("~/Desktop/DCR_0.1.0.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = 
"source")
ERROR: dependency ‘stringr’ is not available for package ‘DCR’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/DCR’
```

so, how to make it automatically load dependent packages when i install package by .gz file?

Comment: try adding the option `dependancy = TRUE` in `install.packages`

Comment: well, i try to use it    `install.packages("~/Desktop/DCR_0.1.0.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source",dependencies = TRUE)
ERROR: dependency ‘stringr’ is not available for package ‘DCR’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/DCR’`    but it did not solve the problem。

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25017195/install-a-local-r-package-with-dependencies-from-cran-mirror?answertab=votes#tab-top