# Automatically install dependent libraries for a self-made package

Tags: r, r-package

I have a question regarding on how to automatically install dependent libraries while installing a self-made package from source.

Basically, the `DESCRIPTION` file looks like:

```
Package: mypackage
Type: Package
Title: mypackage_title
Version: 0.1.0
Author: test 
Maintainer: test <test @example.com>
Description: More about what it does (maybe more than one line)
Depends:
    dplyr, 
    stringr
License: MIT
LazyData: TRUE
RoxygenNote: 5.0.1
```

I followed the [guide](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Package-Dependencies) and created a `.tar.gz` file. When I distribute this package, a user will install from the source. In addition, what I expect is that from this source installation, dependent libraries such as `dplyr` and `stringr` will be installed automatically if those two are not available.

I tested in a virtual machine but ran into the following errors. So any suggestions on this issue? Thanks in advance!

```
install.packages("path_to_my_tar.gz", repos=NULL, type="source")
Error: dependencies 'dplyr', 'stringr' are not available for package
```

### Update: I tried a couple of other approaches but still failed...

#### Approach 1

```
install.packages("path/to/my/package", repos = NULL, type = "source")
ERROR: dependencies 'dplyr', 'stringr' are not available for package
```

#### Approach 2: putting `my package`, `dplyr`, and `stringr` into `path/to/my/package/folder`

```
install.packages("path/to/my/package", repos =  "path/to/my/package/folder/", type = "source")
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository path/to/my/package/folder/src/contrib:
  scheme not supported in URL 'path/to/my/package/folder/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning in install.packages :
  my packageis not available (for R version 3.3.1)
```

#### Approach 3: putting `my package`, `dplyr`, and `stringr` into `path/to/my/package/folder` using `contriburl`

```
install.packages("path/to/my/package", contriburl = "path/to/my/package/folder/", type = "source")
Installing package into my package (as lib?is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository path/to/my/package/folder/:
  scheme not supported in URL 'path/to/my/package/folder/PACKAGES'
Warning in install.packages :
  my package is not available (for R version 3.3.1)
```

#### Approach 4:

> install.packages("ProdComp08032016_0.1.2.tar.gz", repos = c("file://C:/Users/TH2/Downloads/", "http://cran.us.r-project.org"), type = "source")
>   Installing package into :/Users/TH2/Documents/R/win-library/3.3?(as ib?is unspecified)
>   Warning in install.packages :
>     cannot open compressed file '//C:/Users/TH2/Downloads/src/contrib/PACKAGES', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
>   Error in install.packages : cannot open the connection

#### Approach 5:

> install.packages("ProdComp08032016_0.1.2.tar.gz", repos = c("C:/Users/TH2/Downloads/", "http://cran.us.r-project.org"), type = "source")
>   Installing package into :/Users/TH2/Documents/R/win-library/3.3?(as ib?is unspecified)
>   Warning in install.packages :
>     unable to access index for repository C:/Users/TH2/Downloads/src/contrib:
>     scheme not supported in URL 'C:/Users/TH2/Downloads/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
>   Warning in install.packages :
>     package rodComp08032016_0.1.2.tar.gz?is not available (for R version 3.3.1)

Comment: Just to clarify; your virtual machine has a configured internet connection with which it could install said dependencies? What happens if you try to install it from the `.tar.gz` on your build machine?

Comment: @JonathanCarroll, correct. The virtual machine has internet connection. The same installation approach works on my build machine, which had `dplyr` and `stringr` installed before.

Comment: A basic solution: run `install.packages(c("dplyr", "stringr"))` before the `install.packages("path_to_my_tar.gz", repos=NULL, type="source")`. You'll need to update the `install.packages()` call when you add new dependencies to your package, but that should be fine.

Answer (score 3):

## EDIT

As per this duplicate question, [Package dependencies when installing from source in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805049/package-dependencies-when-installing-from-source-in-r), the command

```
install.packages(pkgs = my.package.name, repos = c("file://path/to/my/custom/repo", "http://cran.somepage.org"))
```

can be made to work, if you [create a local R repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905650/creating-a-local-r-package-repository).

The other option is to make the package a GIT project and use

```
devtools::install_local("path/to/package.tar.gz")
```

---

I don't have a package ready for testing, but my guess is `repos = NULL` screws `install.packages` looking for dependencies of your package.

Looking at `?install.packages` looks like you have bad luck without putting your dependencies in the local repository as well:

> Arguments
>
> **pkgs**   character vector of the names of packages whose current versions
>   should be downloaded from the repositories. If repos = NULL, a
>   character vector of file paths of ‘.zip’ files containing binary
>   builds of packages. (http:// and file:// URLs are also accepted and
>   the files will be downloaded and installed from local copies.) Source
>   directories or file paths or URLs of archives may be specified with
>   type = "source", but some packages need suitable tools installed (see
>   the ‘Details’ section). If this is missing or a zero-length character
>   vector, a listbox of available packages is presented where possible in
>   an interactive R session.
>   **lib**    character vector giving the library
>   directories where to install the packages. Recycled as needed. If
>   missing, defaults to the first element of .libPaths().
>   **repos** 
>   character vector, the base URL(s) of the repositories to use, e.g.,
>   the URL of a CRAN mirror such as "http://cran.us.r-project.org". For
>   more details on supported URL schemes see url. Can be NULL to install
>   from local files, directories or URLs: this will be inferred by
>   extension from pkgs if of length one.

Here are my two guesses:

```
install.packages(pkgs = "package", ..., repos = c("file://path.to.tar.gz", "http://path.to.cran.mirror")) # Try to specify the path to your package as another repo
install.packages(pkgs = "file://path.to.tar.gz.file") # Leave repos alone and hope the file:// suffices
```

Please let me know whether they work or not :)

Comment: So you are suggesting that I should put both of my dependency packages (`dplyr` and `stringr`) into my distributed R package, then list their path as part of repo? Is it possible to use an URL for a local install?

Comment: @tao.hong I'm hoping that one of the two calls will work without downloading `dplyr` or `stringr` manually, but according to the docs, placing the dependencies into the same folder seems the only supported way.

Comment: `@AlexR` I tried your suggested method, but still failed... details are in the updates.

Comment: @tao.hong It looks like you've omited the `file://` specifier before the path/to/package/folder. Mind retrying since the docs specifically mention that method 3 would work with the `file://`?...

Comment: I am kind of lost here. You mean sth like this? It did not work.. `install.packages("ProdComp08032016_0.1.2.tar.gz", contriburl = "file://C:/Users/TH2/Downloads/", type = "source")`

Comment: @tao.hong I meant replace "contriburl" by "repos". Basically as it stands in my answer. Especially the one with `install.packages(pkgs = "mypackage", repos = c("file://C:/Users/TH2/Downloads/", "http://cran.us.r-project.org"))` where "mypackage" is the package name looks promising to me.

Comment: @tao.hong I dug around a bit and found this duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805049/package-dependencies-when-installing-from-source-in-r
It basically uses approach 5 (as I suggested), but you need to create an own repo, i.e. you need to create the file it doesn't find "src/contrib/PACKAGES"... Also, this Q contains the same answer as here, using devtools; this seems to require you to make your package a valid git project before .tar.gz-ing it. Either way, you're gonna have to add some new files - I'd go with the git approach, as this seems the cleanest.

Comment: `@AlexR` Yes, I am considering to build stuff from command line or devtools instead of using Rstudio's GUI. I will take a look at later and keep this thread alive. THX!!

Comment: On windows there is no `//` in `file://`.  I've had luck with the following: `install.packages('mypkg', contriburl=sprintf('file:%s', mycrandir), repos=NULL)`

Comment: @TH339 Under windows I seem to need to use three slashes instead of two and no drive letter colon: file:///C/...

Answer (score 1):

No guarantees, but perhaps

```
devtools::install_local("path_to_my_tar.gz")
```

and if that doesn't quite work, try with `dependencies=TRUE`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Tested both suggestions, but without luck... For the `devtools` approach, I got the following error `Error in git2r::discover_repository(path, ceiling = 0) : 
  Error in 'git2r_repository_discover': The `.git` file at 'path_to_my.tar.gz' is malformed'

Comment: I'm not sure why it would be going down that path to begin with, so now I have to ask - how did you create the `.tar.gz` source file?

Comment: I built it in Rstudio by clicking `Build Source Package` through its `GUI`

Comment: @TH339 the archive file you created in RStudio with `Build Source Package`  can only be installed with `install.packages("packagename.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type="source")`. To use `devtools::install_local()`, you need to provide the folder in which you develop the package, before you build it. Then you can run `devtools::install_local("path_to_the_package_creation_folder")`.

Comment: @PaulRougieux, I see. Thanks for proving a solution, Been using `install.packages("packagename.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type="source")` for a while but will look into the second approach you suggested.