# Installing the dependencies of a binary package automatically

Tags: r, r-package

In R, I have developed my own package for work (let's call it 'foo') and I have built the package and produced a binary foo.zip with the dependencies (e.g. ggplot2) listed in the description file.

When I use the R package installer in the packages tab it doesn't automatically download the dependencies from CRAN. Ultimately I don't want the end user to have to do this and I don't intend to load it to CRAN for the time being.

I have a way with:    `devtools::install_dep` but I don't want the user to have to do this!

Answer (score 1):

Use the `remotes` package:

```
remotes::install_deps("~/RStudio/foo/foo.tar.gz")
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't say how you're expecting users to install the package.  I believe if you put it on the web on a CRAN-like repository, and tell your users to install from there, R will by default install dependencies.  This involves telling them how to add your repository to the repository list, so it might be just as easy to ask them to install `devtools` and use `devtools::install_dep`.

Another possibility is to distribute your package in a source version; then this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/38902163/2554330 gives ideas how to proceed. One that works for me to install something like `"~/RStudio/foo/foo.tar.gz"` is

```
install_url(paste0("file://", normalizePath("~/RStudio/foo/foo.tar.gz")))
```

If you are on Windows, you'll probably need a slightly different way to construct the URL.

Distributing binary packages is only convenient if all your users use the same version of R as you do; they aren't guaranteed to work if the minor version number changes.

Comment: I had planned to just send the binary source by email 

When I try install.packages("~/RStudio/foo/foo.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source", dependencies = TRUE)
 
 I get the error:

ERROR: dependency 'ggplot2' is not available for package 'foo'
* removing 'C:/Users/jmm/Documents/R/R-3.5.1/library/foo'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/jmm/Documents/RStudio/foo/foo.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

Comment: Yes, but that's not what my link suggests you should do.