# How to pre-install r packages which are required to run the package you create?

Tags: r, igraph, r-package

I created a new package in R and the functions in my package require pre-installed packages like `igraph`, `dplyr` to run properly. In the `DESCRIPTION` file, I did add these packages in the `Imports` field. But when I run my package, I am getting an error which indicates the packages required have not been installed.

To check what the problem is, I installed the pre-required packages separately and ran my package, and it seems to be working fine then.

This is how my `DESCRIPTION` file looks like

```
Package: xxx
Type: Package
Title: xxx
Version: 0.1.0
Author: xxx
Maintainer: xxx
Description: xxx 
License: GPL-2
Encoding: UTF-8
LazyData: FALSE
Imports: 
    igraph,dplyr,network,gridExtra,centiserve
RoxygenNote: 6.1.1
```

Is there anyway I could load just my package which then loads the pre-required packages automatically, without having to load pre-required packages like `igraph` and `dplyr` manually.

Comment: "But when I run my package" -- Do you mean when you try to install your package, or when you try to load your (installed) package?

Comment: I mean when I load my (installed) package and run the function in it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805049/package-dependencies-when-installing-from-source-in-r ... in case you are asking how to install dependencies when installing a local package from source

Answer (score 1):

This question raises the same issue as [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805049/package-dependencies-when-installing-from-source-in-r). I offer this answer to provide a little more detail and official sources than what is at the other question.

The issue is that you've listed the packages in `Imports` rather than `Depends`. Normally this is preferable, but if you do it this way, you have to take care to import the functions you need in the `NAMESPACE` file. From [Writing R Extensions, Section 1.1.3](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Package-Dependencies):

> The ‘Imports’ field lists packages whose namespaces are imported from (as specified in the NAMESPACE file) but which do not need to be attached.

Therefore, packages in `Imports` aren't loaded when your package is loaded, as would be the case if they are specified in `Depends`.

My advice would be to keep these packages in `Imports`, then specify the necessary imported functions in `NAMESPACE`, either manually adding the statements in that file using syntax like

```
importFrom(foo, f, g)
```

(See [Writing R Extensions, Section 1.5.1](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Package-namespaces)), or via [`roxygen2`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/roxygen2/index.html) tags in your R scripts like

```
#' @importFrom foo f
```

Comment: Keep the answer, it has useful links the dupe does not have. I can dupe hammer if you want.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Sounds good! Thanks